# Optimize/fine tune Android bitmap drawing

Tags: android

If I were to set the pixels (read from a server) on the bitmap and draw on a `SurfaceView` (which is once every 2 to 5 seconds, depending on a certain condition), would doing this using `SurfaceView` be the ideal choice for this? I ask this because after doing some tests I found out that it is taking about 50-70ms to draw on the image excluding the time taken to read the pixels from the server, which is kind of huge. Is this because the view takes time to get invalidated after it is pushed to the message queue? The bitmap is drawn by a simple call to the method on `Canvas` associated with the surfaceview. One more observation was that the drawing was slower on an `invalidate()` and a subsequent `onDraw` call, this seemed strange to me since `Canvas` in onDraw is HWA provided the view is too. Please let me know some hints to make drawing faster or fine tune or if I need to look at other options (NDK maybe?) or if I'm missing something here. Thanks

Comment: you dont use lockCanvas ?

Comment: @pskink, I did and the time to draw in that case was slightly more what I mentioned in the question. I'm basically trying to find what best suits my case. Perhaps SurfaceView is not to be used for something this heavy?

Comment: heavy? drawing one Bitmap is heavy? what am i missing?

Comment: well I did mention its drawn (they are different bitmaps if that is what led to the confusion) every 2 to 5 secs. and the size of the bytes (pixels) tried to draw vary anywhere between 20k to 90k.

Comment: i still cannot see where you canhave performance problems, how many bitmaps do you draw every 2-5 secs?

Comment: sorry for not being clearer. I try to draw 3 to 5 (it has gone upto 7 sometimes) every 2-5 secs. I don't know if that actually qualifies as being "heavy" but thats what I thought.

Comment: no, its quite lightweight operarion comparing for example to any Animation where you draw 20-30 frames per sec

Comment: ok. got that one cleared. but I still dont understand what might be causing this bottleneck, I'm sure theres nothing in the code as it is very straight forward. many posts suggest OGL to be pretty fast in terms of drawing bitmaps. where do you think I should start looking from for this little issue?

Comment: used a traceview? if not give it a try